# Print 1 digit after decimal point in Java

Tags: java

I’m trying to print a number with digits after the decimal point, but i want to show just one digit.

```
ratio = (double) comparisons / arrayLength;
```

(while ratio is double and comparisons , `arrayLength` is `int`).

i'm doing the calculation in one class and add the result to a `string` (when later is returned from a method), and doing the printing in a test class.

i need to change ratio and not allowed to use `printf` in the test class.

thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please search before asking and find several good answers faster than anyone can type a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already keeping the result in a string, you can do this-

```
 String result = String.format("%.1f",ratio);
```

If you want to add the answer to an existing string then you can do this-

```
result = String.format(result+"%.1f",ratio);
```

An example would be like this-

```
 String s = String.format("%.1f",2.3535);
```

> Output- 2.4

Comment: i did that, but now it's print only ratio and not the rest of the string

Comment: Do you want to add the "ratio" to an existing string? Like "The ratio is - 2.4"?

Comment: yes, it's an existing string

Comment: Then do this-
**result = String.format(result+"%.1f",ratio);**
It will concatenate the ratio with the string.

Comment: it worked! thank you very mach

Answer (score 0):

You could explicitly format the number with a [`DecimalFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```java
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("###.#");
String formatted = df.format(ratio);
System.out.printly("ratio is " + ratio);
```